# Why does this code behaves different at different values

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var i = 10000000000;
do {
    i--;
}
while (i !== 0);
//Result: 38 second.

var i = 10000000000;
do {}
while (i-- !== 0);
//Result: 27 second.
//(same result with while (i--)

var i = 10000000000;
do {}
while (i-- | 0);
//Result: 13.5 second.
```

The question is: Why these version get the same time for smaller value of i? If I cut an single zero from i; all versions need 2.2 seconds. (tested even after JIT optimizations - only in V8)

It seems logical that the third version should be always faster but it is faster only for very high values.

It's just a curiosity...not actually important.

Comment: I tried to put these into jsperf but it tends to crash my browsers http://jsperf.com/do-while-speed-test. Keep in mind that different javascript engines will result in different outcomes, as they prioritise different things. It can come down to something as simple as the underlying OS's way of handling numbers. (UPDATE: tests have ran but JSperf is throwing an error about missing its own `name` property. No idea why that happened)

Comment: The last one is quickest because it only iterates 1410065408 times and is actually 1/3rd the speed of the second version, i.e. 104449290 per second
vs 370370370 per second

Comment: Good observation. Didn't observed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor, operational system, and the interpreter can interfere with the speed of you program in ways that are hard to predict. That is why the big oh notation is used to evaluate algorithms.

One of the reasons why the speed could be different here is that with one less zero your value of `i` can be expressed using only 32 bits. So the assembly code generated by the interpreter could perform optimizations and use instructions of 32 bits integers.

Also the value of `i` in the last code is converted to a 32 bit integer changing the number of iterations, and that is why it performs faster when the value of `i` cannot be expressed using only 32 bits.